# USB Installaton of win 10 on vaio laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, bios, windows-installation

I am trying to install win 10 from USB stick on a VAIO VGN FZ160E. The current OS is Windows 7 x64 which I installed from a USB stick about 7 years ago. I have the following situation:

Booting from USB doesn't work from any of USB ports. Booting from USB doesn't also work for installing win7. (I had the idea to clean install win7, as it worked for my current version, and the upgrade it to win10.)

The boot order is correctly set to begin from USB Stick. Another machine could be booted from the same USB Stick. I don't have any option to change the boot setup to legacy etc.

I have tried 3 ways to generate the USB Stick (Tool from Microsoft, manual format and copy with robocopy etc, rufus), with no success of course. I have tried to use Plop Boot Manager to add the option to boot from plop boot device. The option is there but when I select the USB it doesn't work either and stays freezing. I was thinking about the updating BIOS but I'm not sure if this is going to help as it used to work to boot from USB.

Could anybody help me with this case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does USB work in general on this computer? If there is a hardware problem with this
not-new computer, it will be better to wait with the upgrade until you know if the
problem can be fixed.

For upgrading you don't really need a USB boot device, as you may upgrade
directly from within Windows 7.

See the following guides. There is some overlap between them, but also differences.

- [Windows 7, 8.1 & 10 compatibility testing for Windows XP, Vista & 7 computers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_install/windows-7-81-10-compatibility-testing-for-windows/310e06a4-b181-45ec-ae6d-ee93a1632932)
- [Check Get Windows 10 app Compatibility Report for Windows 10 in Window 7 and 8.1](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6728-get-compatibility-report-windows-10-window-7-8-1-a.html)
- [Will your PC run Windows 10? Use the official compatibility checker to find out](https://www.zdnet.com/article/will-your-pc-run-windows-10-use-this-well-hidden-compatibility-checker-to-find-out/)
- [Here's how you can still get a free Windows 10 upgrade](https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/)